# unable to transfer property stored in SOAP UI to the next WS url

Tags: api, soap, soapui

I am using a url to get response from a WS as shown below

http://mysite.com/token/getresponse

where the token is the property I will get in the response of another WS, and store as a property in the SOAP UI.

Now I need help in getting the token value into the next request url along with the other parameters as like http://mysite.com/${token}/getresponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template parameters for your request url. In resource path you type http://mysite.com/{token}/getresponse and then add resource parameter with name "token" and style "template". In your requests you just need to define the value of this parameter.

More information here: http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html#3-template-parameters

Comment: thank you, it worked out I am able to transfer the property into the request url