# Http call parameters SoapUI

Tags: http, rest, soapui

How can I Parameterize an http call parameter in soapui to read parameters from a txt file for each iteration.

If needed can the parameters be encoded(url or gzip) before the call was sent?

Any help (pointers/links/code) is greatly appreciated? Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use groovy script test step to read data from txt file and store the data in TestCase property . 
Something like this would work:

```
String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').text;
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(property_name, fileContents);
```

More information about groovy script steps [here](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html).

You can access this property as ${#TestCase#property_name} in your requests. Then you can use template parameters for your request url - I've already answered about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296028/unable-to-transfer-property-stored-in-soap-ui-to-the-next-ws-url/17312235#17312235).

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong you are asking about parametrization of URL which you send as HTTP Request for your Rest call. Let me explain you with an example :

Suppose you are looking for a resource and invoking the WebService using the GET method by making use of the ResourceID already present in the DB...Parametrize it as below :

http://${#Project#HOST}:${#Project#PORT}/rest/${#Project#WebApplicationName}/Resource/${#TestCase#ResourceID}

where HOST, PORT, WebApplicationName are the Project Level properties and ResourceID is a Test Case Level property(as it may change with the test cases i.e., dynamic in nature).

This is my approach of parametrization instead of taking it from a local file. Hope this helps!